# How to change WP-PostRatings icons?

Tags: wordpress

PostRatings icons.I went my wordpress/plugin/wp-postratings/images/thumbs and changed icons but it did not worked (I also did the same name how was image names.).
So is it possible to change it?

[image: Plugin icons]

[image: My icons]

Comment: Did you make sure they had the correct file extensions and made sure the images were not cached?

Comment: Yea i changed png to gif them. When i put them in folder it is shown like -> http://www.upmatik.com/m/2016/01/20/Screenshot19hrYn.png @Aravona

Comment: Did you flush the cache on your website?

Comment: What? didnt get you. @Aravona

Comment: Well the images might be cached - either use ctrl+f5 to refresh, or another browser, is the issue persisting then?

Comment: So i am doing right? There isnt another solution right? @Aravona

Comment: since you didn't answer my last question I can't help you. It sounds like there is a caching issue. The images will get overridden when the next plugin update occurs anyway.

Comment: I tried mozilla and there is not a image at all @Aravona

Comment: You might want to look at any JS code or how the plugin works then.

Comment: Man okay, i add real .gif and it worked.Before i changed the file extension png to gif.Thats why it dint work.

Comment: change the images through an image editor and you should be fine then.